# Combinatorics problem involving ways to put n indistinguishable balls into m distinguishable boxes where one box must have exactly k balls

Tags: combinatorics

I am having a problem understanding an exercise from a combinatorics textbook. There are n indistinguishable balls and m distinguishable boxes numbered 1,2,...,m. There are two questions :

How many wyas can the balls be put into the boxes such that :

- a.) There are exactly k balls in the first box and every box contains at least one ball
- b.) There are exactly k balls in the first box

For problem (a.) I see the number of ways as equivalent to the number of ways to assign n-k
balls to m-1 boxes with at least one ball in 1 box. My thinking is that we already know that the first box has k balls, so all the variations in the distribution of balls to boxes just include the different ways to assign the remaining balls to the other boxes. A theorem in the book states :

"The number of p-combinations of the elements of t-set A with repetitions allowed, such that element $a \in A$ appears at least once in any of these combinations, is equal to $\binom{p-1}{t-1}$."

In my thinking, an assignment of (n-k) balls to (m-1) boxes is equivalent to an (n-k)-combination of {2,3,...,m}. Each element of the (n-k)-combination is the box assignment of a given ball.

So my answer is :
\begin{equation}
\binom{(n-k)-1}{(m-1) - 1} = \binom{n-k-1}{m-2}
\end{equation}

But in the answer key of the book they have :
\begin{equation}
\binom{n-k-1}{m-1}
\end{equation}

I can't see what I am getting wrong here.

For part (b.) it seems that this should just be the number of (n-k)-combinations of the
set {2,...,m}. Here again I just remove box #1 from consideration and look at the ways to
allocate the balls to the remaining m-1 boxes. Here there is no constraint on how many balls go into each box except for the constraint that box 1 must have k balls. Another theorem from the book covers this more general case :

"The number of p-combinations of the elements of t-set A with repetitions allowed is
$\binom{p+t-1}{p}$."

So my answer for part (b.) is :
\begin{equation}
\binom{(n-k) + (m-1) - 1}{n-k} = \binom{n-k+m-2}{n-k}
\end{equation}

but in the answer key they have :
\begin{equation}
\binom{n-k+m-2}{m-2}
\end{equation}

What am I getting wrong in both of these cases ?

Answer (score 1):

For part (a) you are correct, and the answer key is wrong. For part (b) you’re both right:

$$\binom{n-k+m-2}{n-k}=\binom{n-k+m-2}{m-2}\;.$$

Recall that $\binom{\ell}i=\binom{\ell}{\ell-i}$.